# How to switch monitor display on windows 8 while the screen is blank?

Tags: windows-8, multiple-monitors, hdmi

I was trying to get my laptop to read my ps3 through an HDMI cable and a user online mentionned going into the display settings and switching to the second monitor to get it to work. I went on the windows 8 screen and clicked something on the right that mentionned a second monitor and my screen went black. I've tried everything to try and get it back to normal, including rebooting several times, but nothing seems to work. Laptop works fine, I can see the startup symbol and after I managed to blindly write my password in, I can hear apps such as skype start up. I'm really lost as to what to do and after hours of looking online, I couldn't find a situation that was similar to mine. Any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Press the `Windows Key` + <kbd>P</kbd>, which will bring up the display settings. Because you can't see anything on your monitor use the left or right arrow key and press enter (Repeat this step). Each time you use the `Windows Key` + <kbd>P</kbd> combination, press the left or right arrow key once and hit enter. Eventually you should hit the option that displays the output to your laptop screen.

Comment: was going to say this too, +1 :)

Comment: @Gizmo - Nice :)

Comment: Thank you so much! Windows key + P and then pressing right key and enter worked perfectly. Much appreciated!

Comment: Actually, you can hold down Windows and keep pressing P, just like Alt+Tab.

Comment: Nice. Didn't know that.